# Linux message. Sendto() udp, only recvfrom() raw

Tags: sockets, embedded-linux

We make a network device driver (eth2) to send message by the spi bus. The problems begins when we receive a message.
The driver works fine. We know that the protocol number of the message is

```
htons(ETH_P_IPV6)
```

because the

```
skb->protocol=0x86dd



struct sk_buff *skb;

skb->protocol = eth_type_trans(skb, dev);
```

In device 1 we create a socket to send message:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client)); 
client.sin6_family = AF_INET6;           
client.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
client.sin6_port = htons(20000); 
client.sin6_scope_id=if_nametoindex("eth2");

memset(&from, 0, sizeof(from));  
from.sin6_family = AF_INET6;  
inet_pton(AF_INET6,"ff02::2",(void*)&from.sin6_addr.s6_addr);
from.sin6_port = htons(15118);

bind(sockEnvio,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client));

sendto(sockEnvio, data, localIPLen, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from, sizeof(from)) ;
```

In device 2 we create a socket to receive the message

```
sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IPV6))) < 0)
memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client)); 
client.sin6_family = AF_INET6;           
client.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
client.sin6_port = htons(20000); 
client.sin6_scope_id=if_nametoindex("eth2");

bind(sockEnvio,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client));

recvfrom(sockEnvio,buffer, BUFFER_SIZE , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &from , &from_size);
```

We receive the message, when we change the type of the socket to

```
socket(AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_IPV6))) < 0);
```

Are we missing anything? Could you help us, please?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you send with protocol 0 but receiving with protocol **htons(ETH_P_IPV6)**.

In case of SOCK_RAW you get all the packets from the network regardless the protocol field in ETH header.

You need to init socket at the sender part as following:

`sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IPV6))) < 0)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I do it, but when I try to send with socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IPV6)) the socket failed.